# When will PHP 5.6 be in the official Canonical repos?

Tags: 14.04, php, official-repositories

I imagine it won't up until 14.10 is released, but even if that is the case, could we expect to see it show up in the repos that 14.04 uses?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**Updated:** I Just got an email back from Marc Deslauriers (security engineer at Canonical, so somebody who would know) and the answer is: **Probably never**. Unless something goes catastrophically wrong with 5.5, it'll have security patches backported for the lifespan of 14.04.

> Yes, like most packages in Ubuntu, the security team backports security fixes,
>   including for versions that are no longer supported by upstream.

As of 15.04, the `php5*` packages are version 5.6. However I would not recommend using a non-LTS release on a production server as they *require* release upgrades every 9 months (opposed to the 5 years an LTS gets you).

And the only Canonical-supported version in 16.04 seems to be PHP7.

---

<strike>Around June 2016, maybe earlier, maybe never.</strike> There are a few different forces at play here:

- Ubuntu doesn't do major upgrades on packages [unless it's required or globally desirable](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates).
- [PHP 5.6 is not fully backwards compatible with PHP 5.5 code](http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.incompatible.php), making a mid-term upgrade undesirable; potentially devastating for production servers.
- But [PHP 5.5 will only be supported to June 2016](http://www.zend.com/en/support-center/support/php-long-term-support).

So unless somebody jumps in an plans on manually maintaining 5.5 (stranger things have happened) there probably will be a transition at some point. It's impossible to say when that'll be this far out though.

If you're deploying on 5.5, I'd get testing on 5.6 well in advance, just to make sure you're not caught out. Another option is to use a branch of PHP (like Zend Server) that has commercial support seemingly spanning into the next millennium.

Comment: This is an excellent answer --- 
your second bullet point is precisely why I asked this question, so thank you - !

Comment: I have [submitted an email to ubuntu-devel-discuss](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2014-September/015009.html) asking for clarification. I'll update as I find out more.

Comment: Brilliant-! Thank you very much for the in-depth and truly canonical answer! XD

Comment: JFTR most of the patches that go into PHP 5.6 can be applied to PHP 5.5 with enough care. So running PHP 5.5 might not be as bad as it seems.

I would also suggest to directly test compliance with PHP 7.0 instead of just PHP 5.6, so you can jump to Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Here's the link to the email response: https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2014-September/015010.html

Answer (score 22):

If you really want PHP 5.6 on Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 or 14.10, you can use [this PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php5-5.6):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install php5
```

The default `php5` package dependency will pull `libapache2-mod-php5` that in turn depends on Apache.  If you want to use different PHP SAPI, make sure you explicitly list it when installing, f.e. for PHP FPM use:

```
sudo apt-get install php5 php5-fpm
```

---

*Annotation:* Since December 2015 if you have Apache installed, there is also a dependency on [Ondrej's Apache2 PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2):

```
ppa:ondrej/apache2
```

---

As an option I would strongly recommend to use `ppa:ondrej/php` that includes co-installable PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.0 versions:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
# pull a default PHP FPM (currently PHP 7.0)
sudo apt-get install php php-fpm
# pull PHP 7.0 Apache2 mod_php7 explicitly
sudo apt-get install php7.0 libapache2-mod-php7.0
# pull PHP 5.6 - just CGI SAPI
sudo apt-get install php5.6-cgi
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `php5` includes Apache which not everyone uses. `php5-cli` is more desirable.

Comment: php5-cli is not installable from the PPA.

Comment: `php5` *doesn't include* Apache2 support. `libapache2-mod-php5` is just a default dependency, so you could do `apt-get install php5 php5-fpm` and it won't install `libapache2-mod-php5`.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `php5-cli` is installable from the PPA, but most probably you want `php5-fpm` and a server with FastCGI support like `apache2` or `nginx`.

Comment: For those wondering about the safety / reputation of the ondrej/php PPA: http://askubuntu.com/a/628214/164151

Answer (score 2):

No, 14.10 doesn't have PHP 5.6 (and even if it did, it probably wouldn't gt into the 14.04 repos).

http://packages.ubuntu.com/utopic/php5

Comment: The link is broken and I'm not sure what it should actually be pointing at perhaps this http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/php5 ?

Comment: @icc97 This question was about 14.10, which is now EOL. Nothing to see here anymore.

Comment: Fair enough, I just shed a silent tear every time I hit a broken link. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu 15.04 has PHP 5.6 in it. So if you don't care for LTS, upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04.

So to answer the question: yes. it is now included in the repositories, but only starting with Ubuntu 15.04.

Comment: Actually by the time the next LTS is released, it might very well be PHP 7.something, which has a much stronger value proposition than 5.6.x.