# What php version does ubuntu 14.04 officially support?

Tags: php

So simple question in the title, but did not find on google or in there. Or if there is - maybe you can give keywords on how to find this information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [When will PHP 5.6 be in the official Canonical repos?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527533/when-will-php-5-6-be-in-the-official-canonical-repos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I found an answer right after asking question and pasting exactly the title in the google of this question :)

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

So it is 5.5 as I understand.