# PHP 5.5 support after July 2016

Tags: 14.04, php, support

Will Ubuntu still support PHP 5.5 after it reaches EOL in July 2016?
http://php.net/supported-versions.php

Will be there any backported security updates for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When will PHP 5.6 be in the official Canonical repos?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527533/when-will-php-5-6-be-in-the-official-canonical-repos)

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR Yes.

Ubuntu Security Team will support whatever PHP they have in the LTS releases.  They already do that for PHP 5.4 in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  You have to count on the fact, this will not include all security issues, but only those critical enough (such as remote unauthenticated vulnerabilities).